# How to retrieve xml data using ajax

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to retrieve data stored in XML file using JavaScript. But after clicking on button there is no response. Nothing happens after clicking on button. It is even not showing any error and no output. I am unable to understand what is wrong with following code. Please help.

```js
<html>
<head>
 <title>Requesting XML data in AJAX Student information</title>
<script language="JavaScript">

function getData()
{
 var xhr;
 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  //xhr.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
   }
 else
   {
  // code for IE6, IE5
    xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
    {
      var n=xhr.responseXML;
    dispData(n);
    }
  }
xhr.open("GET","student.xml",true);
xhr.send();
}

function dispData(xmlDoc)
{
 var a,f1,f2,f3,f4,disp;
 
 
 //using javascript properties
 a=xmlDoc.documentElement;
 f1=a.firstChild;
 f2=f1.nextSibling;
 f3=f2.nextSibling;
 f4=f3.nextSibling;
 
 disp="<b>using javascript properties</b><br>";
 disp=disp+"PRN:"+f1.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Name of Student:"+f2.firstChild.nodeValue +"<br><br>Lives in :"+f3.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Contact Details:"+f4.firstChild.nodeValue;
 
 //accessing XML elements by name

 var t=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("stname");
 var f=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("mobile");
 disp=disp +"<br><br><b>Accessing XML elements by name</b><br>Student Name: " +t[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ " <br><br>Call: "+f[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
 
 
  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=disp;
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="background-color:black;color:white">Handling XML in AJAX Application</h1>
<button onClick="getData()">Get the Student Information</button>
<br><br><br>
<div id="div1">
text goes here...........................
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
xml file
 student.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<student1>
   <prn>121</prn>
   <stname>Vijay Sharma</stname>
   <city>Chiplun</city>
   <mobile>94232942090</mobile>
</student1>
```

I changed my XML file.It is working properly with following line of code

```
    var t=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("stname");
    var f=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("mobile");
    disp=disp +"<br><br><b>Accessing XML elements by name</b><br>Student Name: " +t[0].firstChild.nodeValue+ " <br><br>Call: "+f[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

But I found error with following line of code

```
a=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    f1=a.firstChild;
    f2=f1.nextSibling;
    f3=f2.nextSibling;
    f4=f3.nextSibling;

    disp="<b>using javascript properties</b><br>";
    disp=disp+"PRN:"+f1.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Name of Student:"+f2.firstChild.nodeValue +"<br><br>Lives in :"+f3.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Contact Details:"+f4.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

It generate error as
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of null

for following line of code

```
disp=disp+"PRN:"+f1.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Name of Student:"+f2.firstChild.nodeValue +"<br><br>Lives in :"+f3.firstChild.nodeValue+"<br><br>Contact Details:"+f4.firstChild.nodeValue;
```

So script does not work for nodeValue property.
Is nodeValue property is deprecated? If so ,then what I can used instead of nodeValue.
Please help.

Comment: First of all it shows some errors on console. It says that f1.firstChild is null.

Thats because the first child in that file is a empty text node, which therefore has no children. It means that your xml is ill-formatted. Try rewriting your xml in just one line and you`ll see. It will work.

make sure you dont have any white spaces, use a tool to format your file, like http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html#ad-output

Also make sure that your file is correct encoded, and put the attribute encoding into the root tag <xml>

Comment: No, nodeValue is not deprecated. The problem is that f1.firstChild is returning null. You can't call a method, or a property, of a null object.

Comment: I don't understand ,what I should have to change in above code.`f1.firstChild.nodeValue` Why it is returning null